# What is a man who is fond of learning various types of languages called?

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english

Question:- A man who is fond of learning various types of languages is called? 
Ans:

Comment: Ans: the same thing as a woman is called in a less sexist world.

Comment: @tchrist ??? Just add '-trix' to the end. Aviatrix, judgeatrix, polyglotatrix.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best word is *[linguaphile](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/linguaphile)*.

Answer (score 1):

The term that I would use is [polyglot](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/polyglot).

This [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160906123938/http://www.latg.org/2016/07/the-cult-polyglot.html/) suggests that the meaning of polyglot is evolving (online at least) to specifically mean someone who is *deliberately* learning languages:

> This is by no means official, but it looks like in the common online language discourse polyglots are those who have learned multiple languages deliberately, whereas multilinguals acquired them from their environment. With such a division, a polyglot naturally wins more right to be admired as one who has put effort and time into mastering a skill, rather than passively absorbing knowledge from the surroundings.

This article is used as a reference for the wikipedia entry for polyglot.